# Object includes too many columns

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a MySQL table that has the following columns:

- id
- email
- password
- register_date
- active

I use the following code to receive the data:

```
$user = new Users();
$res = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Users::class)->findOneBy([
    'email'    => $data['email'],
    'password' => $data['password']
]);
```

The output is:

> object(App\Entity\Users)#427 (5) { ["id":"App\Entity\Users":private]=>
>   int(14) ["email":"App\Entity\Users":private]=> string(14)
>   "test@email.com" ["password":"App\Entity\Users":private]=> string(7)
>   "mypw123" ["registerDate":"App\Entity\Users":private]=> int(2019)
>   ["active":"App\Entity\Users":private]=> bool(false) }

Well, that object returns more data than I need. What I need are only the values from the columns `email` and `password`.

How could I return an object or an array, that returns only the values from the columns that I need?

Comment: Create method in repository and use it.

Comment: Why do you use findOneBy with email and password parameters (that return one row) and do you want the same values to output? I don't understand

Comment: Do you want an array with *every* Users with email and password information only?

Comment: @AndreaManzi yes, exactly! I just want to know if the values exist in my database.

Comment: I don't see any problem here.

Comment: @u_mulder the problem is the performance. If you have a table with too many columns, I would like to return only the data that I need.

Comment: Create a count query then.

Comment: Just curious why you need to access this data directly this way. If this is related to authentication, the Symfony security component can handle all of that for you safely.

Comment: @Don'tPanic oh I didn't know about that. Thank you for that info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$res = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Users::class)->findBy([
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => $data['password']
]);

if (count($res) > 0) {
    //found
}
```

or like suggests @u_mulder:

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('count(u.id)')
        ->from(Users::class, 'u')
        ->where('u.email = :email')
        ->andWhere('u.password = :password')
        ->setParameter('email', $data['email'])
        ->setParameter('password', $data['password']);

if ($qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult() > 0) {
    //found
}
```